# Container width needs to be dynamic based on the table width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am trying to implement a container for my table and hence chose to use card class. As seen in the screenshot the the container extends to the entire width of the screen. I want the container width to be based on the width of the table. The width of the table in my case can change as the data is rendered
horizontally. How could i make my container dynamic. The horizontal scroll should appear if it goes beyond the screensize. As you can see in the screenshot below it is wrapping to the next line and there is gap on the right sideat the top

screenshot

[image]

html

```
<style>
    th,
    td {
        padding: 7px;
    }

   .scrollClass {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    .fundClassesTable {
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 11px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tableItem {
        text-align: center;
        border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-right: solid 1px lightgrey;
        border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey;

    }

    .rowItem:hover {
        background-color: #f5f7f7;
    }



    tr {
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    th,
    td {
        display: block;
        min-height: 46px;
        min-width: 300px;
    }

    label {
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        vertical-align: middle
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: white;
        background-color: #F59850;
        border-color: #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    .panel-heading .left-label {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 5px !important;

    }

    .panel-heading label {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
    <label for="chk">Invested</label>

</div>

<div class="card scrollClass">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Classes</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <!-- <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right"> <i
                    data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" /> Add
                Class</label> -->
            <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right" (click)="openFundClassModal()"> <i
                data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Class</button>    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

        <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Fund Name</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Class ID</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
                <th class="tableItem"></th>
            </tr>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">
                <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
                    <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.FundName}}</td>
                    <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
                    <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.LegalFundClassId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.PrimaryLegalFundClasses"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Description" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.LegalFundClassName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-datepicker style="width:100%" [format]="'MMMM yyyy'" [topView]="'decade'"
                            [bottomView]="'year'" [(ngModel)]="f.value.InceptionDate"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.InceptionDate | date:"'MMMM yyyy"}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.value.InvestedAmount"
                            style="width: 284px; height: 29.5px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.InvestedAmount | number : '.2-2'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.VehicleTypeId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.VehicleTypes" [filterable]="false"
                            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.VehicleTypeName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.ClosureStatusId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.ClosureStatuses"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.ClosureStatusName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}" id="chk"
                            style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        <label for="chk">Yes</label>

                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.IsSidePocket == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsThematic}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        <label for="chk">Yes</label>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.IsThematic == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.CogencyClassId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.CogencyClasses" [filterable]="false"
                            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.CogencyClassId}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableItem">

                        <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-4"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Edit</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-3"
                            (click)="Update(f.value.Id)">Save</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Delete</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Cancel</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<shared-modal [modalSize]="1" class="survey-edit" [open]="fundClassWindowOpened">
    <div style="width: 100%;" header>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <div style="text-align: right"><button aria-label="Dismiss" class="close"
                    style="margin-top: -48px" type="button" (click)="dismissFundClassModal()">X</button>
            </div>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div body>
        <mgr-addFundClass></mgr-addFundClass>

    </div>
    <div footer>
    </div>
</shared-modal>
```

Applied solution based on Aarons comments

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried. The only difference is that it starts from the left but there is space on the right

Comment: Could it because there is  min-width:  200px; set for td

Comment: For horizontal scroll , i tried applying the scrollclass but that doesnt seem to take effect

Comment: So you want to the columns on the next line if you run out of space but you just want to remove the empty space on the right? Or do you want to disable that the elements go on the next line and you just want a horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: i dont want the columns on the next line but should scroll horizontally to view it. Also the space from the last column and the card div should be eliminated

Comment: The columns should be on the same line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So based on the comments I think I understand you now. First of all lets remove the very outdated approach of using `float: left` to put containers in a row:

```
tr {
  display: block;
  float: left; //<== Remove this line
  min-width: 300px; //<== Optional: Just to make sure your table columns don't get too small if they have less content.
}
```

Let's use something more contemporary like `flexbox`. So add `display: flex;` to your `tbody`.
 Problem is you still got an empty space. To fill that up use [`flex-grow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp) on each `tr`. At the end it comes down to this:

```
.fundClassesTable tbody {
  display: flex;
}

.fundClassesTable tbody tr {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.scrollClass {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: grid; //<== Add this line.
}
```

Here is your example (or http://jsfiddle.net/h5oc70va/1/ if you prefer):

```css
.fundClassesTable tbody {
  display: flex;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 7px;
}

.scrollClass {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: grid;
}

.fundClassesTable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableItem {
  text-align: center;
  border-left: solid 1px lightgrey;
  border-top: solid 1px lightgrey;
  border-right: solid 1px lightgrey;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgrey;
}

.rowItem:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f7;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

th,
td {
  display: block;
  min-height: 46px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

label {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.panel-heading {
  color: white;
  background-color: #F59850;
  border-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.panel-heading .left-label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}

.panel-heading label {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
  <label for="chk">Invested</label>

</div>

<div class="card scrollClass">
  <div class="card-header panel-heading">
    <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Classes</span>
    <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
      <!-- <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right"> <i
                    data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" /> Add
                Class</label> -->
      <button style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right" (click)="openFundClassModal()"> <i
                data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Class</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

    <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">

      <tr>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Fund Name</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Class ID</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</th>
        <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
        <th class="tableItem"></th>
      </tr>

      <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">
        <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
          <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.FundName}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.LegalFundClassId" class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.PrimaryLegalFundClasses" [filterable]="false" textField="Description" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
            </kendo-dropdownlist>
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.LegalFundClassName}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <kendo-datepicker style="width:100%" [format]="'MMMM yyyy'" [topView]="'decade'" [bottomView]="'year'" [(ngModel)]="f.value.InceptionDate" class="form-control  form-control-sm">
            </kendo-datepicker>
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.InceptionDate | date:"'MMMM yyyy"}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.value.InvestedAmount" style="width: 284px; height: 29.5px;" />
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.InvestedAmount | number : '.2-2'}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.VehicleTypeId" class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.VehicleTypes" [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.VehicleTypeName}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.ClosureStatusId" class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.ClosureStatuses" [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
            </kendo-dropdownlist>
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.ClosureStatusName}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
            <label for="chk">Yes</label>

          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.IsSidePocket == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsThematic}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
            <label for="chk">Yes</label>
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.IsThematic == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
            <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.CogencyClassId" class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.CogencyClasses" [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
          </td>
          <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
            {{ f.value.CogencyClassId}}
          </td>
          <td class="tableItem">

            <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-4" (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Edit</button>
            <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-3" (click)="Update(f.value.Id)">Save</button>
            <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3" (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Delete</button>
            <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3" (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Cancel</button>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>


<shared-modal [modalSize]="1" class="survey-edit" [open]="fundClassWindowOpened">
  <div style="width: 100%;" header>
    <h4 class="modal-title">
      <div style="text-align: right"><button aria-label="Dismiss" class="close" style="margin-top: -48px" type="button" (click)="dismissFundClassModal()">X</button>
      </div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div body>
    <mgr-addFundClass></mgr-addFundClass>

  </div>
  <div footer>
  </div>
</shared-modal>
```

If you need any explanation let me know but I believe the code should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Cool. I have applied it and we are nearly there but with a slight issue. When i scroll to the end i see the gap on the header

Comment: Updated the post with a screenshot

Comment: Will take a look at it in a second.

Comment: It could be really obvious and I just don't see it but... I got no clue. Invested half an hour in it and found no reason! This might be something for another question.

Comment: Actually I found the reason. Looking for a solution right now.

Comment: Great Aaron. looking forward

Comment: @Tom add `display: grid;` to the `.scrollClass` class.

Comment: I also edited my answer now to complete it. http://jsfiddle.net/h5oc70va/1/